# Error openssl handshaking server do not respond

Tags: ssl, apache-kafka, openssl, handshake

I have this problem using centos 7 the problem is when i try to connect with ssl and I'am using local internet provider the handshaking will block after client hello,
openssl version: OpenSSL 1.1.0g  2 Nov 2017

```
openssl s_client -connect 151.3.144.205:9093 -state -nbio 2>&1
CONNECTED(00000003)
Turned on non blocking io
SSL_connect:before SSL initialization
SSL_connect:SSLv3/TLS write client hello
SSL_connect:error in SSLv3/TLS write client hello
write R BLOCK
```

If I use a mobile connection the handshaking goes ahead.
the certificates are generating for kafka server and I use the common guide to generate it.

I guess is a problem with openssl

Answer (score 1):

> I guess is a problem with openssl

If it would be a problem with openssl then it would not work with the mobile connection either, assuming that you are using the same openssl with mobile and without.

It is more likely that  there is some firewall which blocks access on your normal connection and that by using the mobile connection you bypass the firewall. Thus, search for the cause of the problem in your network and not in openssl.

Comment: I guess openssl becouse if I use as a server ubuntu the problem not exist, the problem is using centos 7

Comment: @GiuseppeSanna: *"... if I use as a server ubuntu the problem not exist, ..."*  - please provide such essential information in your question and not just as some comment to an answer. Also please provide the configuration of both servers in your question, because maybe the problem lies in the different configuration - like one being properly configured for both IPv4 (commonly used on landline) and IPv6 (often used with IPv6) while the other not.

Answer (score 0):

We found the problem in Centos 7 or Openssl version, we have installed a debian server machine with the same Kafka and zookeper configuration and we have solve the problem. 
I guess that there is a bug in Openssl Centos version, becouse it's impossible
that the communication tcp by ssl secutity were interrupted by the firs client presentation and no server hello response.